# How to set a value into a variable when cursor encounters not found in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, cursors

I have a cursor like this defined in stored procedure written in plpgsql

```sql
cur1 cursor(usid numeric) is select gid, mid from x where userid = usid;
```

I am currently able to exit when cursor encounters a 'not found' case as following

```sql
open cur1(1);
    loop
        fetch cur1 into gid, mid;
        exit when not found;
        raise notice '% %',gid, mid;
    end loop;
close cur1;
```

But apart from exiting at line `exit when not found`, I also want to store a value 1 to variable f, which I've declared in declare section of my function.

I tried following two approaches, but both of them are throwing errors near "when" :

Approach 1:

`set f=1 when not found`

Approach 2:

`select 1 into f when not found`
I can not think about any other way to do this. Is it possible to do assignment like this?

Comment: Use `if not found then … end if;`?

Comment: @Bergi, okay thanks, this worked. This did not come to my mind earlier. My question now seems pretty trivial.